# Computer Certifications and Advancement?

Tags: certification

I am applying for a computer job. I have a BA. I also have a computer certification from before 2000. It was a non-credited course. It was a continuing education course. However, the label "certification" was used. Since this does not have a "license number" I am wondering how to submit this in the online application. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not put it on there, given that it was prior to 2000 any technology or theory you were taught are highly likely to be obsolete, and if not that, highly antiquated at best.

The other fact of the matter it is a course you took 16+ years ago - definitely not something you can say with any veracity that you still remember it, it would look a bit weird to me if I got an applicants resume across my desk that had:
BA/BS in Something Cool, University of Coolsville, 2015
Certification in Floppy Disk Troubleshooting, 1997

It will not add any value, so leave it off.

Comment: Really? I totally understand your logic. However, I don't think it can hurt by leaving it in.

Comment: @SharePointNY YMMV, I hire and interview PMs, BAs and PCs - I cannot in any conceivable fashion think of how it would help. Using a 16 year old cert isn't demonstrating competency (not saying you don't have it, but it's been a long time), it doesn't show a career flow - as that is way out of scope, it does not show a grasp of technology.

Comment: @SharePointNY If you really want to put something up there at least get an industry recognized entry level cert - Server+, A+, MCITP, CCENT or something along those lines.

Comment: So I guess that I should take my degree in computer science off my resume, give that I was awarded it in 1987?....

Comment: @Pete that's your prerogative, a degree and a certification are like comparing orange trees to apples seeds. Generally, one takes a certification to demonstrate prowess in a very specified area, especially in IT. Demonstrating that you know 1990s tech in 2016 is a point so moot it's nonsensical.

Comment: @Pete a degree doesn't need to be updated periodically, certifications do (decent ones anyway) but a 1987 CS degree wouldn't mean anything to me on it's own.